# retrieving Checkbox value within an MVC controller

Tags: html, model-view-controller, view, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have the following code to include a checkbox to show deleted items as part of a list:

```
    <input name="DeletedItems" value="ShowDeleted" type="checkbox">
    <label for="showdeleted">Show deleted itmes</label>
```

This code is located with in the view. My question is: How do I retrieve this value within the controller for this view. I need to retrieve this value in order to to determine whether to show the deleted items or not. Thank you.

Comment: A checkbox is a boolean, so it return true or false, checked or unchecked.

Comment: Are you doing this on form submission or do you need to do it in a more ajax-y fashion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use FormCollection object to retrieve check box value..

**view:**

> <:input name="DeletedItems" value="ShowDeleted" type="checkbox">

**Controller:**

> [HttpPost]
>
> public ActionResult YourAction( FormCollection result) {
>
> string CheckBoxValue=result["DeletedItems"];
>
> }